# Facebook graph not give me access for content although I am a group administrator

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My web-application need to fetch posts from facebook and save content in pages.
I'm have developer account with business access (authomatically contains permissions pages_read_engagement).
I'm try to get API-key by request: `https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=****&client_secret=***`
API return me access token and token type:

> {
> "access_token": "**|**",  "token_type": "bearer" }

After that i try to get feeds via request: `https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/feed?fields=is_published,id,attachments{title},message,created_time,full_picture&access_token=***&appsecret_proof=***`

But API return me error:

```
"error": {
   "message": "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_user_content' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 10,
   "fbtrace_id": "AbApv_PjRlplW2Abv61zNCx"    } }
```

I'm trying to get a long-lived user access token, and it worked correctly, but only 60 days and blocked, Then I have to restore it manually.

Account with API is administrator of group and [Page read content](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference/page-public-content-access) should work

Support replied that the rights pages_read_engagement will be enough, recommended to change the API version to 10.0, but it did not help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#readperms _says_ you need to use a user access token for this request, then that probably _means_ you need to use a user access token for this request …

Comment: Thank you for making me think of creating a system user!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the app key, but it does not work, you need to use the user access token (which has restrictions), or create a system user (which no longer has such restrictions)
I'm create the system user and use his API key.